# PyPlot: hide axes but keep axis labels

Tags: matplotlib, subplot

I have the following code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 4)
for n, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.plot([1, 2], [1, 2])
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xlabel(n)
plt.show()
```

...which displays this:

[image]

What I want is to **hide the black boxes but keep the labels**. I've tried adding `ax.set_axis_off()` but that removes the labels as well:

[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just change the color of spines to None:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 4)
for n, ax in enumerate(axs):
    ax.plot([1, 2], [1, 2])
    ax.set_xticks([])
    ax.set_yticks([])
    ax.set_xlabel(n)
    plt.setp(ax.spines.values(), color=None)
plt.show()
```

[image]